# Windows 10 Balloon Class Name

Tags: c#, c++, automation, windows-10

We have a UI automation tool that waits for a Window Balloon notification to appear.

Until Windows 10, this used to work by searching for a windows object with classname of "tooltips_class32", but since Windows 10 has moved from balloons to its new notification UI, this has broken.

What's the new notification dialog class name?  Or is there a better way to get the currently displayed notification in Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried using Microsoft's Inspect.exe tool to see how it displays the notification?

Comment: Very impressive, as soon as you try to find out then the balloon disappears :)  This was made to not be hackable.

Comment: @HansPassant That happens with combo items as well, but usually the item is still stored in the Inspect tool's tree after the actual object disappears so you can still see its properties.

Comment: No, that's different.  The combo dropdown always closes when you change the focus.  This Win10 counter-measure goes *much* deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows 10 the default is the toast notification, Maybe you can look how to catch those toast notification.

Alternately you can change windows configuration to work with balloons like older windows.

This is how to disable showing balloon notification as toasts:
 1. Open gpedit.msc
 2. User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and
    Taskbar -> "Disable showing balloon notifications as toasts" set to
    "Enabled"
 3. Restart the Windows​

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

If you find a way to catch toast please let me know.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks! doing some tests it I think the toast notification class name is "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow" but didn't test it.  can you please add the registry key required to do the change?